# How can I add value to app.config with loop for, when key need to be increase about value 1?

Tags: c#, app-config

I'm trying to add value- path with loop "for", but also key need to be increase about value 1. 
Like this:

```
<appSettings>
<add key="Path0" value="C:\Users\f.simora\Desktop\DP aplikacia />
<add key="Path1" value="C:\Users\f.simora\Desktop\example />
<add key="Path2" value="C:\Users\f.simora\Desktop\pause" />
```

My code is not working:

```
      private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var appConf = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
        int cnt = appConf.Count;
        if(cnt != 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
            {
               if (i > cnt)
                { 
                    Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Application.ExecutablePath);
                    configuration.AppSettings.Settings.Add("Path" + i, textBox2.Text);
                    configuration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
                    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
                    dt.Rows.Add(textBox2.Text);
                    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Add is not complete", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                } 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you getting some error? or just MessageBoxes poping up?

Comment: just MessageBoxes poping up

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` block is incorrect because before, in the loop, you are increasing your `i` until it reaches `cnt`. And when it is reached the body of `for` loop is not run so the `if` condition is never true.

I think that you might want to change your `if` block into `try-catch` and it probably was the flow that you wanted to have:

```
try
{ 
    Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Application.ExecutablePath);
    configuration.AppSettings.Settings.Add("Path" + i, textBox2.Text);
    configuration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");

    dt.Rows.Add(textBox2.Text);
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Add is not complete.\n" + exc.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

This code will try to run and if it gets any errors it will atch them and display in the `MessageBox`.

**UPDATE**

I think that your problem is not only in a loop but also that after you click the button, you have a loop that adds your `textBox2.Text` to the `Path[i]` value every time, and that text is the same as it does *NOT** change in a loop. I am not sure how you want to set the values but you also need to understand that in your loop it seems that you are just adding the same value to every path on button click event.

Meaning that if you want to add completely new path to the settings you can do it as follows:

```
var appConf = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
var count = appConf.Count;

try
{
    // As OP commented this line fixed the problem
    value = null;

    Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Application.ExecutablePath);
    configuration.AppSettings.Settings.Add("Path" + count, textBox2.Text);
    configuration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);

    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
    dt.Rows.Add(textBox2.Text);
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Add is not complete.\n" + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Comment: It's working but I have bad results, because loop adding path for every key. For example:   <add key="Path0" value="C:\Users\f.simora\Desktop\DP aplikacia,C:\Users\f.simora\Desktop\example" />
    <add key="Path1" value="C:\Users\f.simora\Desktop\example" />

Comment: What is the value of your `textBox2.Text`?

Comment: "path" type- string from folderBrowserDialog

Comment: @FilipŠimora are you sure that you dont select multiple folders?

Comment: I select just one folder and I also see it in textBox...I don't know where older path remains in memory...I thought that loop was wrong

Comment: Well it seems that you just add that path to every Path[i] each time you click the button

Comment: yes, exactly and I need just add path to new key when I click the "add" button

Comment: So you mean you need to add the next i+1 key with new path?

Comment: @FilipŠimora i added possible fix in the update to the question please try it now

Comment: I tried it, but still the same results.                                                                  
<add key="Path1" value="C:\Users\f.simora\Desktop\example" />
    <add key="Path2" value="C:\Users\f.simora\Desktop\pause,C:\Users\f.simora\Desktop\pause" />
    <add key="Path3" value="C:\Users\f.simora\Desktop\RPA,C:\Users\f.simora\Desktop\RPA,C:\Users\f.simora\Desktop\RPA" />

Comment: Are you sure that your textbox has only last item?

Comment: Can you show the code where you set text to the `textbox`?

Comment: I add to your update source code just one line in "try": value = null; and It's working, thank you very much for your help @MarkiianBenovskyi

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is wrong

```
for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
{
   if (i > cnt)
```

The if condition will never get executed where you wrote your actual code.

You need to remove that condition

Comment: what is the value in textBox2.text?

Comment: I tried it without condition IF, but I have these results:   <add key="Path0" value="C:\Users\f.simora\Desktop\example,C:\Users\f.simora\Desktop\pause,C:\Users\f.simora\Desktop\DP aplikacia" />
    <add key="Path1" value="C:\Users\f.simora\Desktop\pause,C:\Users\f.simora\Desktop\DP aplikacia" />
    <add key="Path2" value="C:\Users\f.simora\Desktop\DP aplikacia" />

Comment: textBox2.text, value is path, type is string

Comment: can you please give example string which you input in textBox2

Comment: C:\Users\f.simora\Desktop\example

Comment: If that's the case "C:\Users\f.simora\Desktop\pause,C:\Users\f.simora\Desktop\DP aplikacia" from where are you getting this values?

Comment: from config file in Debug